# How to setup a Magento environment on Windows 8?

Tags: php, apache, magento, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

This is a Q&A post about how to setup a Magento environment using the Bitnami VM ware Ubuntu image.

I've tried various different ways to install Magento on Windows and always had problems. Especially installing it directly on to Windows 8.1 because Windows 8.1 uses the localhost (port 80). Even after stopping all the apps that could be using it (e.g. IIS).

After lots of Google'ing I found the Bitnami website and the VM ware image.
But even their documentation has gaps.

So I wanted to document the steps I took to install the Bitnami VM ware Ubuntu image on Windows 8.1 to hopefully help people that want to do the same.

Comment: Use Xampp. You can install it in a few clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to setup Magento**

1. If you don’t already have VMWare Player installed go to https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0, download it and install it
2. Go to https://bitnami.com/stack/magento/virtual-machine and download the Bitnami Magento Ubuntu VM image zip file
3. Unzip the downloaded zip file. If you extracted the zip into your current folder you should now see a folder called *bitnami-magento-1.8.1.0-1-ubuntu-12.04*
4. Start VM Player
5. Click the **Open a Virtual Machine** option on the right hand side of the VM Player window. This will display an Open Virtual Machine dialog.
6. Navigate to where you extracted the bitnami-magento-1.8.1.0-1-ubuntu-12.04 folder. Open the folder and select the **bitnami-magento-1.8.1.0-1-ubuntu-12.04.vmx** file
7. You should now see bitnami-magento-1.8.1.0-1-ubuntu-12.04 listed and selected in the VM Player window. Click the **Edit virtual machine settings** option on the right hand side to display the Virtual Machine Settings dialog
8. On the Hardware tab, change the Memory value to the appropriate value. I set it to 1024 MB
9. In the same list select the Network Adapter item. Then change the Network Connection (on the right hand side) to **NAT: Used to share the host’s IP address** and click the OK button to save the changes and close the dialog
10. Click the **Play virtual machine** option in the VM Player main window
11. The server will now boot up and display a login prompt. Once booted up It’ll show some yellow text saying something like `You can access the application at http://192.168.230.130`. Make a note of the URL as you’ll need it later to access Magento in your web browser.
12. It should now be prompting you to login. Enter `bitnami` as the login. And `bitnami` as the password
13. It will then ask you to change the password. First enter `bitnami` as the current password, and then enter your new password.

And that’s it. 
You can now use Magento in your web browser by entering the URL you took a note of, and appending it with /magento.
e.g. `http://192.168.230.130/magento`

And you can access the Magento Admin pages by appending /magento/admin to the URL you took a note of.
e.g.  `http://192.168.230.130/magento/admin`. The username is `user` and the password is `bitnami1`

**USEFUL TIP** 
If you clicked your mouse pointer on the VM Player window and you can no longer see your mouse pointer press `CTRL+ALT` to get your mouse pointer back again.

---

**How to setup FTP**

1. (If it’s not already running) start the Bitnami’s Ubuntu Magento VM you setup in the steps above, and log in using `bitnami` as the username and the new password you entered.
2. You should now see **bitnami@linux:~$** with your cursor after it in the VM Ware player window. Type `sudo mv /etc/init/ssh.conf.back /etc/init/ssh.conf` and press RETURN
3. Enter your new password when asked and press RETURN
4. Then enter `sudo start ssh` and press RETURN
5. For the next bit you’ll need a FTP client application. I used FileZilla which you can download from https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client. Start FileZilla.
6. Press `CTRL+S` (or click the File\Site Manager… menu item) to open the Site Manager dialog
7. Click the New Site button and enter a name for the site e.g. `Bitnami Magento`
8. On the right hand side it displays the site properties. Set them as follows:

   a. **Host**: Enter the IP Address from the URL you took a note of when you setup Magento in the How to setup Magento section above. i.e. aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd

   b. **Port**: Leave it empty

   c. **Protocol**: Select **SFTP – SSH File Transfer Protocol** from the drop down

   d. **Logon Type**: Select **Normal** from the drop down

   e. **User**: Enter `bitnami`

   f. **Password**: Enter your new password
9. Click the Connect button

FileZilla will now connect, and enable you to upload / download files.

**USEFUL TIP** 
The Magento files are stored in:
*/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs*

---

**How to setup phpMyAdmin**

1. Open FileZilla and download the `/opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/httpd-app.conf` file to your local PC
2. Open the downloaded file in WordPad (or your favourite code editor. E.g. Visual Studio). But don’t use Notepad as it’ll display all the text on one line
3. Change the `Allow from 127.0.0.1` line to `Allow from all`
4. And change the `Require local` line to `Require all granted`
5. Save and close the file
6. Using FileZilla upload the file you just edited back to `/opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/httpd-app.conf`, overwriting the existing file
7. We now need to restart the Ubuntu server for the settings to take effect. In the VM Player window type `Exit` to log off
8. Now click the Player toolbar button in the VM Player window and click the **Power\Reset** menu option (and click the Yes button to the warning message box that’s displayed)

And once it’s booted up again it’s ready. 
You can now use phpMyAdmin in your local web browser by entering the URL you took a note of, and appending it with /phpmyadmin.
e.g. `http://192.168.230.130/phpmyadmin`

To login enter `root` as the username. And `bitnami1` as the password

**USEFUL TIP** Now you are up and running it’s a good idea to take a copy of the folder where you unzip the VM image as a backup.

So if you every need to start again with a clean install you can simply delete the existing folder and copy it back again using your backup copy.

Answer (score 0):

Using something like WAMP or XAMP has everything you need to create a webserver - Apache, PHP and MySQL.

Magento, like WordPress, is simply a CMS solution but Magento is aimed directly at ecommerce.